# How to make these type of graph

Tags: autocad

[image]

How to make this style and which software

Answer (score 1):

The lower pattern is an artistic creation. It presents nothing measurable because there's shown no connections to any measurement system. We have your word "graph" but I ignore it as long as no numeric nor qualitative measures appear.

The upper one is made to resemble some management or technical thing presentation, but I'm sure it's finally constructed in the same way as the lower one. That's "Draw one rectangular block which is designed so that tiling it creates a repeating pattern with no seams.Then use it as a plane filling pattern". The same method can be used to make other seamless plane filling patterns which divide the plane to equal rectangles (there are infinitely other, mathematically more complex plane filling ideas which cannot be constructed in this way).

This is my attempt to make something which loosely looks the same as your lower image. It's not exact. A better replica could be made by drawing on your image, but hopefully you get the idea. This can be done in Illustrator, Inkscape, Affinity Designer or any other vector drawing or 2D CAD program. I made it in Illustrator.

[image]

A) draw a 2 node Bezier curve where the endings are horizontal

B) make a 180 degrees rotated copy, move it downwards and complete to closed shape with 2 exactly vertical line segments.

C) insert a rectangle which meet the curve exactly in the corners and only there.

D) draw the red shape which meets exactly the top and left edges of the rectangle. Make a 180 degrees rotated (green) copy and place it as mirrored against the bottom and right edges.

E) Remove the strokes and give solid fill colors. The rectangle is orange here and the rest shapes are grey.

F) Group the pieces to keep them easily together. Create horizontally, vertically and horizontally+vertically flipped copies.

G) move the groups together so that the edges snap exactly. This shape can be tiled manually or it can be used in vector drawing prograns a plane are filling pattern. In illustrator one simply drags version G to the fill swatches collection.

In the next image the new "fill pattern" is used to fill a rectangle and an irregular shape:

[image]

Illustrator is handy because it allows adjusting the pattern size even afterwards without changing the size nor the geometric form of the filled shape.

Drawing this without any obstacles happens only after one has trained properly the basic usage of the drawing program including the Bezier curves, node editing and using snapping and alignment operations to place items exactly.

To stay in truth one can also do the same in raster image drawing programs. Another  good thing to know is that many programs have "mirror drawing modes" which may help the basic construction. I have not used them.